# How to list PHP table query as non repeatable heading

Tags: php

I have a PHP table which consists of three catagories:
finit "material"
disc "discription"
size "dimension"

Similar 'finit' comes in different 'disc' and 'size'
I would like to display the results in a way that 'finit' are displayed only once depending upon the quantity while 'disc' and 'size' are listed within the table under their associated 'finit'

I am able to display 'finit' only once if it contains multiple discriptions etc.
But the listings are not properly set within the table.
they are listed directly under 'finit' and horizontally listed.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM prime order by finit asc";
$info = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$finit = $rows['finit'];

?>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Discription</th>
    <th>Dimension</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($info)):
    if($rows['finit'] != $finit) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$rows['finit'].'</td></tr>';
        $finit = $rows['finit'];
    }
    echo'<td>'.$rows['disc'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.$rows['size'].'</td>';
endwhile;
?>
</table>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is unclear what exact table structure you _want_ here, so please add a proper example of that.

Comment: Your current code makes rather little sense, because you are outputting disc and size in TD elements that are not even within a TR.

Comment: Adding a TR to disc and size lists everthing vertically. I would like for the results to be displayed horizontally under their corresponding heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was not generating correct HTML which may well explain the presentation issues. You would also have lost the first `finit` value. See comments in code

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM prime order by finit asc";
$info = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// this will cause the first finit to be completely lost
//$finit = $rows['finit'];
$finit = NULL;
?>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Discription</th>
    <th>Dimension</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($info)):
    echo '<tr>';
    if($row['finit'] != $finit) {
        echo '<td>'.$row['finit'].'</td>';
        $finit = $row['finit'];
    } else {
        // when you dont print a finit, you need to output something in that column
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    }
    echo '<td>' . $rows['disc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rows['size'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
endwhile;
?>
</table>
```

#### UPDATE

To format the table so that the `finit` value is always on its own row followed by rows containing only the other 2 columns, you could try.

All you have to remember is that you have to output the same number of `<td>`'s on each line, so in this case 3, unless you use the `colspan="2"` attribute, but try that once you have the simple route working.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM prime order by finit asc";
$info = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// this will cause the first finit to be completely lost
//$finit = $rows['finit'];
$finit = NULL;
?>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Discription</th>
    <th>Dimension</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($info)):

    if($row['finit'] != $finit) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['finit'].'</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        $finit = $row['finit'];
    }
    echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rows['disc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rows['size'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
endwhile;
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the advice. I now understand the structure better. However the first NULL after every 'finit' is not being inserted, thus the row is pushed to the left while all subsequent outputs are aligned properly

Comment: WOOPS!!! Spotted a typo. See the changed code on line `echo '<td>'.$row['finit'].'</td>';` I removed the `</tr>` that should not have been there. Copy/Paste gets me all the time :)

Comment: That fits everything nicely. If I were to want the output similar to the structure prior to the omission of the TR where the first row contains only the 'finit' voice with 'disc' and 'size' NULL and the next row begins the 'disc' ans 'size' listing do I add another if statement where 'finit' is nulled?

Comment: See the UPDATE.